# My PendingIntents and System time change

Tags: android

Ok, guys, I have this repeated tasks to do, so I schedule cupple Alarms:

```
private static void scheduleAlarm(Context context, AlarmManager alarmManager, String action, long interval) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(action), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + interval, pendingIntent);
}
```

But, when I change system time, all my Alarms are broken, i.e. they eventually fire, but when the system time becomes the same as time for alarms.

How do I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user changes the system time, an event is broadcast with this Intent action: `android.intent.action.TIME_SET`

You can listen for this Intent and reschedule your alarms.

Comment: Can I obtain the time difference between what it was and what it is now?

Comment: Not that I know of. You would need to save the clock time in a file or SharedPreferences beforehand and compare it to the current clock time after you receive the broadcast Intent.